# Resolution problem

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, clip, landsat, resolution

I have a Landsat TM image and in QGIS I used Clipper to crop my image. Then, I tried to reprojected it via Warp (Reproject) and the pixel size goes 29.9936,-29.9936. I do not understand why this happens. I want then to preprocess this image in Grass. Will I have a problem?

Comment: What's the problem, what would you like to achieve?

Comment: I want resolution 30,-30 because I will preprocess this image in Grass.

Comment: To respond to comments it is best to use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with the additional details.

Comment: Set the desired resolution with -tr http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html. By default gdalwarp tries to avoid resampling and it lets the pixel size to change when it converts from one projection into another.

Comment: Because I am new in QGIS, how can I do this?

Comment: gdalwarp -tr 30 30 -s_srs epsg:xxxx -t_srs epsg:yyyy input.tif output.tif. But people will be much more willing to help you if you can show that you have done some work for resolving the problem by yourself and you ask for help with the final detail that stops you.

Comment: please edit your question and add the parameters used, i.e. source and output espg codes. LANDSAT TM L1 products comes with a spatial resolution of 30 meters and is already projected to UTM. Thus I wondering what were you triyng to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the projection, probably, but with the clipper. When you clip a raster pixel size changes, by default.
For example, clipping ASTER GDEM are ESPG:2039 changes the cell size from 30, -30 to 30.0735,-30.0976. In order to overcome such an issue, you should use the "clip raster by extent" or "clip raster by mask" geo-algorithm from the toolbox panel, under GDAL/OGR>Extraction.

In the tool's window, use the additional parameters slot to set the output resolution, i.e

```
-tr 30 30
```

See image below.
[image: Example]

That should fix your problem, unless your original TM image already has a spatial resolution of 29.9936,-29.9936.